# arithmetic operations on enum values

Tags: c#, .net, enums

What arithmetic operations are supported on c# enums? Surprisingly, I was unable to find it via neither google, nor wikipedia and stackoverflow.

Can I add two enum values **without any cast**? Add arbitrary constant to a value or subtract it?
Or does enum guarantee that a value of that type is always one of the defined enum values or their bitmask?

```
class ... {...
enum WeekDays : byte { Sun = 1, Mon = 2, Tue = 3, /* and so on*/ Sat = 7 };
public static bool IsWeekend (WeekDays _d) {
/// Can I be sure here that _d has value from 1..7? May it be any of 0..255?
}
```

I know about bitwise operations, It seems reasonable to support them for representing flags.

Wikipedia tells us, my sample also allows `_d - 1` or `WeekDays.Tue - WeekDays.Mon`, that can be useful for strictly ordered sequential enums, but I cannot find any standard reference, could you, please, point me?

Comment: Can you not just test it and see what happens?

Comment: My point is to know the standard, not a certain compiler behavior. First, I want to be sure, my code will be correct for any compiler supporting standard c# (MS, Mono, <what else>). Second, I want to read something useful from the corresponding standard article to be better prepared for my c# test.

Answer (score 7):

The following operators can be used on values of enum types: `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `+`, `-`, `^`, `&`, `|`, `~`, `++`, `--`, `sizeof`.

Comment: Thank you. How did you find that? Any reference, manpage?

Does `+` here mean `<enum value>+<enum value>`?

Comment: Does `-` stand for binary minus? Similarly, is `<enum val>+<enum val>` allowed?

Comment: @gluk47, Underlying type of each element in the enum is integral numeric type, except `char`. So enums have the same operations as, for example, `int` data type.

Comment: char cannot be an underlying type. _The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong._ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx). Wikipedia says enum values cannot be multiplied either. Among other reasons for my post, I have a test question «can binary operator % be applied to enum values». I need some reference for my answer)

Comment: And in fact enums do not have `operator +` or `operator *` that allow both operands to be of some `enum` type.

Comment: The C# Language Specification identifies enum operations under the section forthe operation. For example, relational operations have a paragraph about valid operators on the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664726(v=vs.71).aspx page; namely, the enum values are cast to their underlying types before applying the operator. Likewise for addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an arithmetic operations, do not use `enums`, use `numbers`. 
`Enums` is a naming convension for numeric values to make them more human readable and allow having a *combination* of them. That is actually the reason that you didn't find anything about that on internet, cause it's not soemthing that should be done with `enums`.

Comment: I'd like to find the chapter of standard explicitly allowing or prohibiting arithmetic operations, just to be sure and have a references for, saying, my institute teacher.

I've also found that `<enum value>+<const>` is allowed as well as `<enum value>-<enum value>`, so I'm interested what else makes sense from the point of C# devs, what assumptions should I make when using enum values in my code.

I'd personally prohibit any operations upon enum values, having a possibility of explicitly allowing bitwise math, I agree with you)

Comment: @gluk47: keep in mind that enums are just integers, so they support all set of possible arithmetic operations. The thing is, like I said, it's just not a case to use them on enum types, that is. But they are **not** prhibited.

Comment: Actually they are prohibited. At least VS2008 raises an error if I try to add or multiply two enum values. The operation can be proceeded with casting both operands to the underlying type, but my question was about operators directly applicable to enum values.

Comment: @gluk47 - What error are you getting exactly.  I don't see any reason you cannot add to enumeration values, they are just integer values, casting might be required.

Comment: *but my question was about operators directly applicable to enum values*. I can cast, yes, then everything wiil be okay. The question is more syntax-related, what can I do without cast.